# Does using IF LET act like closure

Tags: swift, if-statement, closures

Let's assume function calculate() takes 30 seconds to return an int

**update/edit:** I neglected to mention let's assume this is on a background thread and not the main thread.

```
calculate() -> Int{
    let anInt = ...//task that takes 30 seconds to complete

    return anInt

}
```

If I am using `if let` to conditionally bind the value of calculate to a variable like below:

```
if let theIntIWant = calculate() as? String {
    print("the value I want is: \(theIntIWant)")
}
```

Will this `if let` function similarly to a closure, where theIntIWant will not be evaluated until `calculate()` returns its value? I am trying to understand when I need to use a closure for asynchronous tasks and am not sure I would need it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with closures, nor have you said anything about `calculate` being asynchronous. Nor has it anything to do with `if let`! Your question actually has to do with *threads*.

The rules are simple enough. You *must* not block the main thread for any length of time. If `calculate()` has the ability to return a value after 30 seconds of work, it must be called *only on a background thread*. If, having called it, you want to do something with the result that involves your properties, the interface, or other non-threadsafe things, then you need to get back onto the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `theIntIWant` will not be **assigned** until after `calculate()` returns.